# Check out and check in a document from a Sharepoint doc-library using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint-2007

How to write such interaction for a SharePoint document-library:

`open file -> check out file`

`library -> download file -> editing -> updload file`

`library -> check in`

Comment: What have you tried? Have you even started work on this? Do you even know what `SPWeb` is?

Comment: I need to do checkout and checkin files with wpf-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to open the SPItem for the given file, and that is after you open the containing Document Library.

So, the loose pseudo is something like

- Open Site Open Web within site
- structure Open List / SPDocumentLibrary in Web
- Open Item in List
- Reference Item.File
- Checkout
- Get file stream and save it to disk
- Do edits
- Add file back
- Check-in